# How to access Google Cloud Natural Language API behind proxy C#

Tags: c#, .net, http-proxy, google-cloud-nl, google-natural-language

> I am trying to access Google Cloud Natural Language for text analytics. The
> code is working fine from open internet, but not working from my
> company network. I am new to this Google API. I have no idea of  how
> to configure my company proxy in the code for calling API.

**Below is the code I am using to call the API.**

```
                    string jsonPath = "sentimentAnalysis.json";
                 
                    LanguageServiceClientBuilder builder = new LanguageServiceClientBuilder
                    {
                        CredentialsPath = jsonPath
                    };

                    LanguageServiceClient client = builder.Build();
                   
                    var response = client.AnalyzeSentiment(Document.FromPlainText("Hello World."));
                    var sentiment = response.DocumentSentiment;
                    var Sentences = response.Sentences;
```

> I have gone through below links to set proxy, but not got required
> information.

[Refer .net section](https://medium.com/google-cloud/accessing-google-cloud-apis-though-a-proxy-fe46658b5f2a)

[My issues is similar to this](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-dotnet/issues/3112)

The Json file contain Google Language API Configuration.

```
{
  "type": "",
  "project_id": "",
  "private_key_id": "",
  "private_key": "",
  "client_email": "",
  "client_id": "",
  "auth_uri": "",
  "token_uri": "",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "",
  "client_x509_cert_url": ""
}
```

> Can any one please provide a way how to configure proxy in the above
> code.

Comment: Something like this? https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-dotnet/issues/1832

Comment: @gunr2171 Thanks are for the link but LanguageServiceClient class  do not have anything like HttpClient to set proxy.

Comment: any solution here please.